# How can I solve about The repository does not have a Release file?

Tags: updates

for install pytorch, I install CUDA, cuDNN, etc.
after install pytorch and I do `sudo apt update`,
then error appears like this,

```
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.1.23  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.1.23  InRelease                
Get:3 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.1.23  Release                  
Err:3 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.1.23  Release                  
  File not found - /var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.1.23/Release (2: No such file or directory)
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-8-local  InRelease [1,575 B]           
Hit:4 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:8 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                  
Hit:9 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease          
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Get:11 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.1.23  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)